# How to publish website in IIS 7, in place of Default Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, website-hosting

I have created a ASP.NET website and deploy it in IIS 7 (in place of Default Web Site). When I type `localhost` in address bar of browser it shows it perfectly. But when I type my Internet IP address, it shows IIS 7 screen, it does not show `Default.aspx` page. But when I type `IP Address/Default.aspx` then it shows ok.

Now I want, when I type my Internet IP address `Default.aspx`page should open directly.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your default document so that `Default.aspx` has the highest priority.

Under Default Web Site, find `Default Document`, then add "default.aspx" if it isn't there, and use the arrows to move it to the top.

Alternatively you could just remove the `iisstart.htm` file all together.